# PHP DOM getElementsbytagname() getElementById()

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, domdocument

I'm working in PHP and looking at the DOM to parse html and find certain information on the page.

I have code working well using the `getElementsbyTagName()`:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $node) {
          $array_data[ ] = $node->nodeValue;
        }

print_r($array_data);
```

On the page I'm looking at there are a lot of `<div>`'s.
The div i'm interested in has a unique id on the page.
I thought I could select this specific information By updating my code to look at the id as below:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementById('tree___34LHOENOP7') as $node) {
          $array_data[ ] = $node->nodeValue;
        }

print_r($array_data);
```

This code does not seem to work.
The html:

```
<div id="tree___34LHOENOP7" style="margin-top: 5px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; height: 528px; overflow: auto;">
<ul><li style="list-style-type:none;"><span style="cursor:pointer;color:#D99F00;" onclick="prtv_C_E(this,'ExpandableRegionClickHandler','',2,true);(2,this);">UK</span><img src="https://images... " title="re-centre map here" onclick="ExpandableRegionClickHandler(2,this);" style="display:inline;margin-left:7px;cursor:pointer;"><ul style="display:block;"><li style="list-style-type:none;"><span style="cursor:pointer;color:#D99F00;" onclick="prtv_C_E(this,'ExpandableRegionClickHandler','',59,true);ExpandableRegionClickHandler(59,this);">Channel Islands</span><img src="https://images... " title="re-centre map here" onclick="ExpandableRegionClickHandler(59,this);" style="display:none;margin-left:7px;cursor:pointer;"><ul style="display:none;"><li style="list-style-image:url('http://images…’);"><a class="MapEventName" href="http://www... /guernsey" onclick="EventSpanClick(1439,this);" onmouseover="EventSpanMouseOver(1439,this);" onmouseout="EventSpanMouseOut(1439,this);">Guernsey</a></li>
```

Comment: can you share your html source?

Comment: Sure, i have tried to copy the html source into my original question but it was refused as it was too long.  Would you like a url link to see the html source ?

Comment: just share the part of html.

Comment: sure, i've added that section of the html.thanks

for more info the data that i was looking for is Guernsey.

Comment: hope my post will help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you out, `DOMDocument::getElementById` will return `DOMElement Object`.

```
$domObject= new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadHTML($source);//put your complete source html string here
$result=$domObject->getElementById("tree___34LHOENOP7");//this will output DOMElement Object
print_r($result->nodeValue);
```

Comment: thanks for looking into this code, using this code the page loaded fine but nothing was returned.  i will look into the code you supplied some more. thanks again

Comment: @Jeanclaude just put your html content here https://eval.in/ then submit and share the url so that i can look into your html as well

Comment: Hi Sahil, I have posted the php and the html of the page it's looking at.  Thank you again for looking into it!
the code you provided which i have used in my updated php is definitely looking at something, but the returned array is empty.

Comment: @Jeanclaude I have researched on it and i got to know that you are not able to do this thing because `$output` you are using with curl will not contain `tree___34LHOENOP7` id because `http://www.parkrun.org.uk/events/events/` is dependent on some data from other url, just by doing curl request you will not able to achieve this, unless you know the actual call this website is doing on their `js` which is providing data in that `div`

Comment: Hello @Sahil thank you for researching this.  I understand that I can't pick this id out whilst I'm using curl.  Even though I'm using curl I am able to pick out other data on the page using `getElementsbyTagName()` but I understand it may not be possible to find the `tree___34LHOENOP7` id using `getElementById`.  Thank you again for your assistance with looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation explain well:

**getElementbyId:**

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID; the ID is a string which can be used to uniquely identify the element, found in the HTML id attribute

**getElementsByTagName:**

> The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live
>   HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

You don't need to use foreach with getElementById, because you get only one element.

Comment: Thanks for this comment.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the names `getElementsByTagName` has the **plural** *elements* but `getElementById` has the **singular** *element*.

When you use `getElementsByTagName` you have to loop over the result.

When you use `getElementById` there is nothing to loop over. You get a single result. Remove the loop.

```
$node = $dom->getElementById('tree___34LHOENOP7');
$array_data[ ] = $node->nodeValue;
print_r($array_data);
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment.  Using this code returns an empty array.  Would you like a link to see what html source it is looking at?